# Search variable in python function (not in file) : vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to modify `vimrc` such that when I can search a variable inside a python function(excluding the same variable name in other function)
e.g I have a python file

```
def fun1():
    a = 5
    b = 0
    c = a**b
 
def fun2()
    a = 5
    b = 0
    c = a+b
```

What I want is when my cursor is in `fun1()` it only highlights the variable of a that I searched in `fun1()` and not in `fun2()`

Comment: There is not builtin option to do this. What is your use case?

Comment: I have a file with around 20 functions operates on the same set variable when I search it highlights all those variable which confuses me

Answer (score 0):

(I think you could probably get better answers on [vi & Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). However I've been explained that the question *is* on-topic here. So +1.)

I don't think there's a straightforward, purely in-Vim solution, neither I think it's worth it that you spend some time for (trying) implementing it, *and this is my answer*.

I would suggest however, that you give a look at the [Tagbar plugin](https://github.com/preservim/tagbar). Why? [Look at this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/fc85311154723793776aed28488befdfaab36c42/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f5366394c7332722e706e67): a Python file on the left, and its class/function structure on the right.

Another useful plugin is [YCM](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/). This plugin offers semantic completion for many languages, including [Python](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/#python-semantic-completion), and that could help you a lot.